# Facebook Advanced Search Page

Tags: facebook

Twitter has two search pages

- https://twitter.com/#!/search-home
- https://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced

Does Facebook allow advanced search operators when using their engine? For example "This exact phrase"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with Facebook Search

https://www.facebook.com/search/str/frenchtoast/stories-keyword/

Posts about "FrenchToast"

More info available at http://search.fb.com/